# Unchecked call to List<T>

Tags: java, android

Android Studio  shows this warning:

> Unchecked call to List as a member of raw type 'ConnectionSuccess

How can I skip this warning should I check for the type or what?

---

### Please help.

```
  public class RequestTask {
        private Context mContext;
        ConnectionSuccess connectionSuccess;
        RequestHandler requestHandler;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public RequestTask(Context context, ConnectionSuccess connectionSuccess) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.connectionSuccess = connectionSuccess;
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        }

        // Request a string response
        public void MakeRequest() {
            String URL = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.menu_url);
            if (ConnectionTracker.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
                progressDialog.show();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                        new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                try {
                                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
                                    Response response1 = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);
                                  response1.setItemsList(response1.getItemsList());


 //the warning shows here

 connectionSuccess.onResponse(response1.getItemsList());

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Error handling
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.error_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                // Add a request  to RequestQueue.
                MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            } else if (!ConnectionTracker.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class More extends Fragment implements ConnectionSuccess<Data> {
     @Override
        public void onResponse(List<Data> result) {
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public interface ConnectionSuccess<T> {
            void onResponse(List<T> result);
   }
```

---

```
public class Data {
    @SerializedName("arabic_title")
    String arabic_title;
    @SerializedName("english_title")
    String english_title;
    @SerializedName("url")
    String url;

    public String getArabic_title() {
        return arabic_title;
    }

    public void setArabic_title(String arabic_title) {
        this.arabic_title = arabic_title;
    }

    public String getEnglish_title() {
        return english_title;
    }

    public void setEnglish_title(String english_title) {
        this.english_title = english_title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}



@SerializedName("data")
    List<Data> itemsList;

public List<Data> getItemsList() {
    return itemsList;
}

public void setItemsList(List<Data> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}
```

Comment: ConnectionSuccess has a type parameter, but in your constructor arg and field declaration you are not passing it a type parameter. You may mean both to be ConnectionSuccess<Data>

Comment: Like this
public class RequestTask<Data> {
    private Context mContext;
    ConnectionSuccess<Data> connectionSuccess;
    RequestHandler requestHandler;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public RequestTask(Context context, ConnectionSuccess<Data> connectionSuccess) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.connectionSuccess = connectionSuccess;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
    }

Comment: Thanks that helps the warning goes away you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface ConnectionSuccess<T> {
    void onResponse(List<T> result);
}
```

`ConnectionSuccess` has a type parameter `T`, but in your constructor arg and field declaration you are not passing it a type parameter. You may mean both to be `ConnectionSuccess<Data>`

This will allow the compiler to figure out that when you call `connectionSuccess.onResponse(response1.getItemsList())` that it should expect an argument of type `List<Data>`